# Image resizing Java

Tags: java, image, image-processing, image-resizing

I have a weird problem with resizing images and can't figure out what I'am doing wrong. I've read lots of posts wwhich basically have the same code as I:

(I use the java library Scalr)

```
File image = new File("myimage.png");
File smallImage = new File("myimage_s");
try {
    BufferedImage bufimage = ImageIO.read(image);

    BufferedImage bISmallImage = Scalr.resize(bufimage, 30); // after this line my dimensions in bISmallImage are correct!
    ImageIO.write(bISmallImage, "png", smallImage); // but my smallImage has the same dimension as the original foto
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the indication that something is wrong?  If your code is throwing an exception `catch (Exception e) {}` is going to pretty much leave you in the dark as to what happened.  Have you stepped through the code with a debugger?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/

Comment: i just left the unnecessary code out, i have error handling etc in my code. I dont get any exception or anything else. The "resized" image is just the same size as the original

Comment: Why use a special library?  [Just use Java.](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/)

Comment: Scalr works just fine - bISmallImage has the correct size. Just converting the BufferedImage back to a File doen't work as expected. (I tried it with plain java before as well)

Comment: Sorry I missed your comments indicating as much. My eyes just zeroed in on the empty catch block. :} Thanks for the follow-on comment to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see anything wrong with your code.

I pulled it into a quick test project in Eclipse targeting Java SE 7 and using [imgscalr 4.2](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/#download) on Windows 7 Pro 64-bit:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.imgscalr.Scalr;

public class ScalrTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File image = new File("myimage.png");
        File smallImage = new File("myimage_s.png"); // FORNOW: added the file extension just to check the result a bit more easily
        // FORNOW: added print statements just to be doubly sure where we're reading from and writing to
        System.out.println(image.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(smallImage.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            BufferedImage bufimage = ImageIO.read(image);

            BufferedImage bISmallImage = Scalr.resize(bufimage, 30); // after this line my dimensions in bISmallImage are correct!
            ImageIO.write(bISmallImage, "png", smallImage); // but my smallImage has the same dimension as the original foto
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()); // FORNOW: added just to be sure
        }
    }

}
```

With the following `myimage.png`...

[image: myimage.png]

..., it produced the following `myimage_s.png`:

[image: myimage_s.png]

Maybe there is an environmental issue that's hamstringing your code, but possibilities that come to mind would come with a clear error.

Comment: yeah, you're right. I tested it in an extra application as well. I think my  problem is not java related, but something else. thanks thought for testing my problem and driving me in the right direction!