# Re-sizing the .png image in java

Tags: java, image, printing

I have an image which comes in as 4inch x 6 inch dimensions with 300 dpi. I am trying to get it printed on a printer which has paper slightly lesser in dimensions (3.8 * 5.8 inches)

I tried to do it as below but its not working. The image is cut off at the sides.

```
attr_set.add(new MediaPrintableArea(0f, 0f, 3.8f, 5.8f , MediaPrintableArea.INCH));
Doc doc= new SimpleDoc(fis, flavor, attr_set); 
job.print(doc, null);
```

Can someone help re sizing the image as per printer paper setting without losing resolution. Sorry i have never worked with images and printing in java before.

Thanks

Comment: Could you add an image of expected output and actual output? Maybe the link since you don't have enough reputation, but we can edit so images appear :)

Comment: All you've done is crop the image. You need to rescale the image pixels, as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/q/24689255

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is to edit the file with some kind of photo editing software (ie. PhotoShop) before importing it to your package.

Comment: That defeats the purpose doing it pragmatically, which is why he's asking on a programming forum

Comment: yes..  its all part of a continuous process. I cannot edit it using photoshop it should be  java programmed.